# How to empty/destroy a session in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-variables, session-timeout

I can't seem to find it anywhere... How do I delete/destroy/reset/empty/clear a user's session in Rails? Not just one value but the whole thing..

Answer (score 218, accepted):

To clear the whole thing use the reset_session method in a controller.

```
reset_session
```

Here's the documentation on this method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000668

> Resets the session by clearing out all
>   the objects stored within and
>   initializing a new session object.

Good luck!

Comment: For database-based sessions (which you should probably use) you can expire through a query: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry

Answer (score 51):

session in rails is a hash object. Hence any function available for clearing hash will work with sessions.

```
session.clear
```

or 
if specific keys have to be destroyed:

```
session.delete(key)
```

Tested in rails 3.2

**added**

People have mentioned by `session={}` is a bad idea.  Regarding `session.clear`, Lobati comments-  It looks like you're probably better off using reset_session [than session.clear], as it does some other cleaning up beyond what session.clear does. Internally,  [reset_session calls session.destroy](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/afc2b424e27fe48f83d5d1be73a8fadc38499c0c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L350), [which itself calls clear as well some other stuff.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb#L79-L87)

Comment: Anybody have any thoughts on the merits of this method vs the one recommended by Gdeglin?

Comment: This can be used when you want to retain other parameters but delete one particular key value pair.

Comment: I suppose I was referring to the use of either `session.clear` or `session = {}` vs the use of `reset_session`. Are they identical?

Comment: This will not reset the session at all, it will assign a local variable. Never use this technique to reset the session:

    session = {}

Comment: The [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), on section _5.1 Accessing the Session_ recommends to use reset_session if you want remove script-inserted key/value pairs (ex: Something inserted from a controller) and generate a new session. If you want reset only the key/value pairs you set, set those keys to nil.

Comment: Downvote for same reason as @alexspeller mentions. `session = {}` does nothing but set an empty local variable, which creates an insidious bug in your application and still leaves the session floating around untouched.

Comment: @lobati What about the other thing the answerer suggested, session.clear  Is that OK?   What exactly is the difference between session.clear and the other answer of reset_session?

Comment: @barlop It looks like you're probably better off using `reset_session`, as it does some other cleaning up beyond what `session.clear` does. Internally, [`reset_session` calls `session.destroy`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/afc2b424e27fe48f83d5d1be73a8fadc38499c0c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L350), which [itself calls `clear` as well some other stuff](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb#L79-L87).

Answer (score 9):

to delete a user's session

```
session.delete(:user_id)
```

Comment: Careful, you can delete the user record from the database!

Comment: @Arthur That's not true. But you'll only delete the :user_id key from the session and not the whole session

Answer (score 5):

To clear only certain parameters, you can use:

```
[:param1, :param2, :param3].each { |k| session.delete(k) }
```

Answer (score 5):

add this code to your ApplicationController

```
def reset_session
  @_request.reset_session
end
```

( Dont know why no one above just mention this code 
as it fixed my problem )
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RackDelegation/reset_session

Comment: I find that `@_request.reset_session` and `reset_session` both work and maybe do the same thing?

Comment: Oh my god i was searching fot 2 weeks and dealing with this issue. Thank you so much for the support.