# How to delete cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to delete the session cookie and havent had any success.  Ive tried reset_session, cookies.delete(:id), cookies.clear and nothing has worked.  I feel like I'm missing something, can anyone help?
Rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will give you the answer:

[StackoverFlow Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405635/how-to-empty-destroy-a-session-in-rails)

> session[:current_user_id] = nil

This works fine in Rails 3.2.1

> reset_session

Shreds everything...

Comment: I've tried both, but the session cookie is still on the browser. It almost feels like I'm dealing with a bug.

Comment: Digging a little deeper,; if I debug and watch the cookie and session objects, they do get set to nil, but the cookie still exists.  Am I expecting to much to expect to see the cookie vanish from the browser?

Comment: An empty cookie will exist for any website you visit.
If its at nil there wont be any details there.
If you want to physically delete the cookie file, it will be heavy due to multiple browsers having diferent ways of doing it.

Comment: The session objects at nil is not what you want then? 
You want to remove the cookie?

Comment: My expectation was that cookie.delete would remove the cookie from the browser, not just set it to nil.  I really dont want any browser specific code so I think I just need to change my expectation.  THanks for your help!

Comment: That expectation will be met in some browsers.
But for example IE only erases cookies even if at nil on exit.