# Rails - Delete a session without initialising a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I want to delete a session during an `after_filter` execution if a condition is valid.

The controller's method `reset_session` is of no use since after "deleting" the current session, it creates a new one.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405635/how-to-empty-destroy-a-session-in-rails

Comment: You could try with `session.destroy` or `session.clear`.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul that one is using the `reset_session` method that initializes a new one after the deletion of the current.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `reset_session` method they are using `session.destroy` to remove the session

You could try with

```
session.destroy
```

or

```
session.clear
```

Please see this link [reset_session](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionDispatch/Request/reset_session)